# Python: numpy, how to len of csv

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have 2 files:

**`res_my_inp.csv`** : http://ge.tt/8Fa4d512/v/0?c

**`res_my_out.csv`** : http://ge.tt/8Fa4d512/v/1?c

I want to get **matrix** from `res_my_inp.csv` and **array** from `res_my_out.csv` (get only 1 column)

My code:

```
import csv

in_filepath  = os.path.abspath( "res_my_inp.csv" )
out_filepath = os.path.abspath( "res_my_out.csv" )

def ReadCsv( fileName, mode ):
    in_file = open( fileName )
    reader = csv.reader( in_file, delimiter = '\t', quotechar = '"' )
    if ( mode == 'input' ):
        data  = [[]]
        for row in reader:
            data.append( row )
    elif( mode == 'output' ):
        column = 1
        data   = []
        for row in reader:
            data.append( int( row[column] ) )

    data.pop(0)
    return data

X = np.asarray( ReadCsv(  in_filepath, 'input'  ), 'int' )
Y = np.asarray( ReadCsv( out_filepath, 'output' ), 'int' )

print(len(X))
print(len(Y))
```

Why `len(X) = 100`, but `len(Y) = 99` ?

Comment: validate your true output with rather `X.shape` and `Y.shape` instead of `len()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length discrepancy is because this line:

```
        data = [[]]
```

is different from this line:

```
        data = []
```

In the `'input'` branch you've got an empty list at the start of your `data` list that isn't present in the `'output'` branch.

Comment: Yes, but why in Y only 99 elements, when in the file 100?

Comment: Because of this line: `data.pop(0)`